# Two layer cache implementation in django

Tags: python, django, caching, redis, memcached

My final goal is to have a two-layer cache for every function that I want (probably a self-implemented decorator is needed)
I have multiple VMs running the same Django server. The first cache layer is memory, and the second layer is a shared Redis between VMs.
The process works as follows, a function is decorated for two-layer caching. In the case of function calls, the server looks for the item inside its in-memory cache. if it couldn't find it, then it will check in the shared Redis.

How can I achieve this?

I already have this code snippet:

```
from cachetools.func import ttl_cache
from cache_memoize import cache_memoize

@ttl_cache(maxsize=settings.A_NUMBER, ttl=settings.CACHE_TIMEOUT)
@cache_memoize(settings.CACHE_TIMEOUT)
def my_fucn(arg1, arg2):
    some logic here.
```

Django settings:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django_redis.cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': env.str('REDIS_MASTER'),
}
```

I read this ([How to use 2 different cache backends in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949271/how-to-use-2-different-cache-backends-in-django)) but I don't know whether it's possible to use them as a decorator.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added correct methods, but the order of decorator is not correct, so what's happening in your case is it queries Redis first then local cache then function call.

```
from cachetools.func import ttl_cache
from cache_memoize import cache_memoize


@cache_memoize(settings.CACHE_TIMEOUT)
@ttl_cache(maxsize=settings.A_NUMBER, ttl=settings.CACHE_TIMEOUT)
def my_func(arg1, arg2):
    pass
```

Now it will check ttl cache first if there's data it will return if not it will call Redis cache method to get a result if Redis cache has data it will return otherwise it will call the function to get the result.